# Sci Fi novel - Evil man named Cotton in colony, red licorice, wasps

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am just looking for a novel I read from my local library 10 odd years ago, to be honest I don't remember the actual story, but I found it interesting and want to take another look.

All I remember is the evil guy (from memory) being a bloke named Cotton who lived in some colony and ate a lot of red licorice or something.. Something about wasps/mosquitos as well? (Unless he was a wasp?)

There was a female authority character too named Juru or  Jira.

Sorry for lack of specifics, help would be appreciated.

Comment: it was definitely sci fi, it was from the sci fi section!

Comment: Well, if the villain was a wasp....

Comment: mate i don't know, i know it sounds silly... i don't think he was a wasp

Comment: it sounds kiddish i know with the wasp thing, but it definately was not a kids book, i found it hard to follow at 12, which is why i wanna find it again

Comment: Do you remember anything about the setting? Africa, Asia, South America, the Pacific? Island, forest, desert, prairie, mountains? Was it set it the future, present, past? Were there any science-fictional props like rayguns, spaceships, robots, time machines, ETs?

Comment: What I mean is, you say it was in the sci-fi section of your library, but you haven't mentioned any aspect of the story that would classify it as sci-fi. Maybe it was mis-shelved? Happens all the time.

Comment: Red licorice features in Stephen King's novella [The Library Policeman](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40704), though the rest of your description doesn't match.

Comment: If the colony was one on another planet, it would definitely qualify as SF.

Comment: @starpilotsix If the colony were on another planet, I think the OP would have mentioned that? Also if the wasps and mosquitoes were as big as chickens, or if the red licorice came from a replicator, it would qualify as sf.

Comment: @user14111 Would he?  Or would he just say "colony" like he did and assume we'd get it?  I don't typically, in everyday life, see anyone pointing out someone lives in a colony today even when we do... so if the book was set in the modern day at all, "colony" probably wouldn't be memorable or worthy of mention if it were anything other than another planet.  I mean, "alien" could refer to immigrants, but if someone comes on to a SFF SE and says they remember a book about an alien that killed a bunch of people we don't assume it's not SF because he didn't specify the alien came from outer space.

Comment: @starpilotsix It crossed my mind that it might be an extraterrestrial colony. That's why I posted my initial comment, inviting the OP to clarify and expand on his description. To which he replied "it was in the sci-fi section". By the way, when I hear about "an alien that killed a bunch of people," I *don't* assume that the alien came from outer space.

Comment: beowulf's children by niven, pournelle and barnes had storms of a killer bee like insect and a central character called cadman, set on a colonized world. its close ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the correct book (2014 so too recent, Cotton is the protagonist's distant cousin, only a side reference to red licorice), but for the sake of later querents *[The Boys of Blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boys_of_Blur)*.

> Twelve-year-old Charlie Reynolds has no idea what to expect when he moves to Taper, Florida --- Taper’s beloved high school football coach, Coach Wiz, has died, and Charlie’s stepfather, Prester Mack, is going to replace him. Charlie can tell that there is something strange about this place, but can't quite put his finger on it until he meets Cotton, who tells him that this small town is filled with haunting tales about the sugar cane fields. Charlie begins to wonder if his encounter with an enigmatic man named Lio, the mysterious disappearance of Coach Wiz's body and the blood markings on the town church lend credence to the stories.

It ultimately turns out that there are zombies named "the Gren" in the swamps, governed by a swamp witch. Like I said, it's not a great match, but someone else looking for books set in swamps with characters named Cotton might be helped. :)